# I need the "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP", but I don't found it in my reference window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, reference, visual-studio-extensions

I am setting up a UWP-Desktop bridge and for that I need the "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP".

The problem is, I don't have the entry in my reference window to include the extensions.

Windows 10 SDK v. 10.0.17763.132

http://prntscr.com/nibwjd - So should be and that's my reference window: http://prntscr.com/nibx1g

Comment: Do you have the Windows 10 SDK installed? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: What type of app is the "AutoClickerApp" in your screenshots?

Comment: Have you checked that you've installed all UWP options? Similar to [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aad77136-29e3-4eec-b277-2b06c3a0b620/missing-desktop-extension-sdk?forum=vssetup)?

Comment: Oh thank @LanceLi-MSFT. Just mklink from real path to true path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. The problem was the path of my Windows Kits.
The right path for the kits: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10